# Trouble with the command line client(or gradle) when trying to implement Google Calendar API into Spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, google-calendar-api

I am trying to implement Googles Calendar API into my Spring-boot project and I am following this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java

I completed step one and when I moved onto step two gradle wasn't installed so I installed chocolately via admin cmd and then installed gradle by inputting "choco install gradle" - The directory I used for this was that of the project I'm working on.

When I type in "gradle -v" it shows: [image]

Then  as I continue the tutorial I try to input what it tells me in step two but the following happens:

[image]

"The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: The syntax of the `mkdir` is incorrect. Windows does not like / as path seperator. Going with `src\main\java` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks that sorted my issue!